# Binding error from Class when adding extra column from SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor-pages

I am using Entity Framework to retreive data from SQL.

I have two razorpages using the same class for binding

1. Razorpage 1. using a query that returns all available columns from the table
2. Razorpage 2. using a query that adds a new column to the results that is not in the table

looks something like this

```
result = await _context.tblTime.FromSql("...").ToListAsync();
```

So in the 2:nd one the query is adding a column to the result that is not in the table.

If I add the column as a property to my Class I get the error: The required column 'Rsp' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation from my first razor page but not from the 2:nd razorpage.

So the first razorpage generates an error because the column "Rsp" is in the class but not in the table and not in the resultset

I also noticed that I needed to declared Rsp as virtual in the class to get the correct value

```
public virtual string Rsp { get; set; }
```

How can I make this work for both my razorpages?

Using Visuas Studio 2017, v15.5.2 and Asp.NET Core v2

Comment: can you add a column called Rsp to your sql table? would that fix the issue? Otherwise create a model that doesnt have Rsp in it for adding to the data table.
you can always transform your data into a view model after getting the data you need from sql..

Comment: thanks, not sure I follow, how do I transform the data to a view model after getting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your comment I'll put an example of populating a view modal from your raw sql query.

lets say you have a view model like this:

```
 public class TimeViewModel {
        public string Rsp { get; set; }
        public int Minutes { get; set; }
        public int Seconds { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can select from your raw query into a new list of your view model:

```
result = await _context.tblTime.FromSql("...").ToListAsync();
List<TimeViewModel> viewModel = result .Select(a => new TimeViewModel()
                                              {
                                                   Minutes = a.Minutes,
                                                   Seconds = a.Seconds
                                               }).ToList();
```

You can add extra rows of timeViewModel with the Rsp field no without a problem.

Then just return your view model to the view.